# Concept of Schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: database-design, postgresql, schema

I am not able to understand concept and usage of schema in PostgreSQL. I have no idea how it can affect my database design. 
Why should I use it?

Can it affect me in future if I decide to not think about them right now and worry about them later?

Explanation with an example will be nice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) in postgres are used mostly for namespacing and sometimes for security.

Namespacing because two objects can have the same name in different schemas, and are then referenced by `schema.object` notation - especially useful in conjunction with [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html#AEN75437) (many contrib modules do this, eg [xml2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xml2.html)). Security because you can now do `grant ... on all tables in schema`.

Comment: One of the very cool things you can do with schemas is to replace default objects from other projects.  for instance we use wikis in individual schemas and a view to allow for wikimedia integration with our app at work.  to the wikimedia code, it's just regular old wikimedia in a schema, but in fact the users and groups come from our app, and override what wikimedia would expect to see.  this way the user / group info isn't stored twice, once in our app and once in wikimedia, but just in our app.

Comment: I like that :-)